# Use NGINX as reverse proxy for development of one path?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

Tell me if I'm crazy here.   I have an old website I inherited with multiple applications under it.   We are in the process of redoing it completely, but for now nobody can get it to work and debug locally mostly due to authentication issues.   I'm having a hard time getting it to deploy and being able to debug it on the server as well.   There is a base site and many applications under it.  What I would like to do is be able to debug it locally and browse to the site, where only calls to my path are sent to the server I'm debugging locally.

- Web server: https://devmachine
- Local debug: https://localhost:44000/Dashboard

All the authentication is setup with federated security that cannot be changed, so redirects go to https://devmachine.   I was thinking I could change 'devmachine' to 127.0.0.1 in my config and use nginx to reverse proxy to the actual IP of the devmachine, or localhost:44000/Dashboard for that one path.  Is this possible?  So if I go to https://devmachine the browser should resolve that to 127.0.0.1, and nginx should call https://192.168.10.33 (the real IP of devmachine) and pass on the results.  If I go to https://devmachine/Dashboard nginx should proxy the call to https://localhost:4400/Dashboard and pass on the results.

How will SSL verification work, does nginx have to handle that or can it work as a pass-through so it uses the devmachine cert and the browser won't know any different?   What about the dev cert for localhost?  I was thinking the config could look like this:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://192.168.10.33
}

location /Dashboard {
  proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:44000/Dashboard
}
```